# Workbench vs Activity Bar vs Side bar in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

What's the difference between the following entities in VSCode?

- Workbench
- Activity Bar
- Side Bar

Do they refer to the same entity?

## Sidebar

[image]

## Activity Bar

[image]

## Workbench

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: demo]

"Workbench" refers to the overall Visual Studio Code UI that encompasses the following UI components:

- Title Bar
- Activity Bar
- Side Bar
- Panel
- Editor Group
- Status Bar

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface

Comment: Thanks Alex -- Regarding the definition of Workbench you provided, doesn't that list include *all* UI components in vscode? And if so, why is it that in e.g. [the list of all command IDs available for keyboard bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) some of them are prefixed with `workbench` and some of them are not? 

E.g. 

`editor.action.marker.prevInFiles`
vs
`workbench.action.showCommands`

Comment: `editor.action.marker.prevInFiles` Markers - is a widget to navigate problems that exists only in editor. That's why it has such prefix. You can see it's `when` context in Keybindings GUI that it will only work when `editorFocus`. `workbench.action.showCommands` should work from anywhere. That was just an example, probably not all commands make sense and you can actually delete the `editorFocus` context from `editor.action.marker.prevInFiles`.

Comment: Thanks Alex - so if I understand what you wrote correctly `workbench.*` would **only** contain shortcuts that apply to *all* UI components, and if something **only** applies to the `editor` it would go under `editor.*`? Just want to make sure I understand why `editor.action.marker.prevInFiles` is **not** prefixed with `workbench`, (e.g. `"workbench.editor.action.marker.prevInFiles"`.)